# firebase: please verify the new email before changing email. (auth/operation-not-allowed)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I was using Firebase authentication by Email/Password on my react-native app and doing emailUpdate through the app successfully , until i decided to move to new Firebase project with the same app changing the Config keys only.

Every thing is working fine I can delete existing email, create a new email , only when I try to updateEmail, I receive the following error :

[firebaseerror: firebase: please verify the new email before changing email. (auth/operation-not-allowed).]

Note: I am not using or requesting any email verification in my code.

Thanks for any support !

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same issue.

Comment: What version of Firebase were you using in your app vs now? I have a similar issue in my apps, and the only difference I can tell is the version of Firebase each app is using. My app that uses Firebase 8 doesn't run into this problem, while my app that uses Firebase 9 has the exact same issue you are describing. Perhaps there was an update to add this 'security feature' that requires email verification?

Comment: The same version, the only change I made is that i created a new firebase project.

Answer (score 5):

I've been emailing with Firebase Support and it seems as though this is, indeed, a bug in the system. However, the representative emailing me provided a temporary workaround, and it works!!

The 'issue' is caused by 'email enumeration', which is now enabled by default as of September 15th, 2023 according to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/release-notes#September_15_2023).

The workaround is to [disable email enumeration](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable_email_enumeration_protection) for your project.

It's a little complicated (pending on your comfort level with command line), but basically you just install Google Cloud SDK (I did it with hombrew). If you do it with home-brew, you can run the commands in any directory, though I ran everything from home directory (not root of project)

```
brew install --cask google-cloud-sdk
```

then initialize the project:

```
gcloud init
```

Once done, you can simply follow the instructions provided in the link to disable email enumeration for your project, which should solve the problem.

This worked for my iOS projects, but since the solution isn't tied to specific platform, it should work for React Native as well.

I'll post back here once I receive the proper solution to the problem, as from what I can tell the email enumeration is a security feature that could be beneficial to prevent fraud in your app. Until then, I hope this helps!

Comment: Great! I've wasted a day checking the confis on Firebase console and got no ideas what went wrong. Finally, a working solution for a new bug on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for this, spend all day trying to figure out why I couldn't upgrade an anonymous account to an email account. Disabling email enumeration fixed it. Lots of the docs are wrong now after this change.

Answer (score 3):

**Uncheck email enumeration protection**

[image: uncheck Email enumeration protection]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by replacing the `updateEmail()` function with the `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail()` function.

After `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail()` is called, firebase sends a confirmation email to the new email address. Once the user clicks the link in the confirmation email, they can sign in with their new email address. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#verifybeforeupdateemail).

Here's a code example that shows the old code and then the new code. My code is written in TypeScript.

```
// old code
async function firebaseEmailReset(user: User, email: string) {
    try {
        await updateEmail(user, email);
        await signOut(firebaseAuth);
        window.location.reload();
    } catch (error: any) {
        handleFirebaseError(error.message);
    }
}

// new code
async function firebaseEmailReset(user: User, email: string) {
    try {
        await verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(user, email);
        await signOut(firebaseAuth);
        window.location.reload();
    } catch (error: any) {
        handleFirebaseError(error.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: When i do  await verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(user, email); I get Firebase: Error (auth/requires-recent-login).

Comment: @insivika You need to reauthenticate the user before updating email

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to convert an anonymous user to email and password user. All I did was update firebase to 10.6.0 and it started working as intended.
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#firebase-console