Flutter FirebaseAuthException in sendPasswordResetEmail
If a user wants to recover their password, they activate the function below
void resetPassword() async {
      final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();

      if (!isValid) {
        return;
      }

      formKey.currentState!.save();

      try {
        final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
        changeIsResetValue(true, "$unicodeCheck Password reset link has been sent to your email");
      
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print(e.code);
        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
          changeIsResetValue(true, "$xUnicode This user does not exist");

        } else {
          
          if (!context.mounted) {
            return;
          }
          AlertDialogs().fatalErrorDialogMessage(context, e.toString());
        }
      }

      // close keyboard
      if (!context.mounted) {
        return;
      }
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    }

Now if I enter an existing email it works fine and I can change the password, the problem is that it never seems to get in on FirebaseAuthException catch even if I enter an email that is not registered I never receive an error as if it never entered the catch block.
How do I return an error if the user does not exist? What am I not understanding?

add a catch block too to see the issue instead of relying on just FirebaseAuthException

On Firebase projects create since September 15 2023, the protection against email enumeration attacks is enabled by default. Once consequence of that is that the API no longer returns user-not-found codes on such projects, as that is a type of message that allows the attack. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77147854 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250121

Go ahead and used this code to better understand what's returning or being thrown from that method:
void resetPassword() async {
  final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();

  if (!isValid) {
    return;
  }

  formKey.currentState!.save();

  try {
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
    changeIsResetValue(true, "$unicodeCheck Password reset link has been sent to your email");
  
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print("FirebaseAuthException code: ${e.code}");
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      changeIsResetValue(true, "$xUnicode This user does not exist");
    } else {
      print("Unhandled FirebaseAuthException: ${e.toString()}");
      if (!context.mounted) {
        return;
      }
      AlertDialogs().fatalErrorDialogMessage(context, e.toString());
    }
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    print("Exception occurred: $e\nStack Trace: $stackTrace");
    if (!context.mounted) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // close keyboard
  if (!context.mounted) {
    return;
  }
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
}
 

what I did was add a catch (all) below that will print everything that's being thrown.
